# C# read decimal number from keyboard

Tags: c#

Hi I have just started learning C# and I have written a simple program which is supposed to read values entered from the keyboard. The code I use to do that is:

```
    try {
    x=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine(),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        }
    catch (System.FormatException)
    {//error message }
```

The problem is that if I enter 1,2 the value stored in x is 12.
Is there any way I can read this value as 1.2, so converting the comma into a point?

Also if I enter 1,,3 the value would be 13 and no error is generated.

Comment: Do you want to store "1,2" as 1.2 because `,` is the decimal separator in your computer's regional settings? Or do you _also_ want to accept "1.2" regardless of the locale? Because I'm tempted to upvote Steve's answer, as I really don't like string replacements to parse input, but it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead and pass the appropriate culture info.

```
double x;
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT"); 
if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, out x))
    MessageBox.Show("It is a double number");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not a double");
```

You could also try with the simple version that doesn't require a CultureInfo and NumberStyles parameters, but, in this case, you get the conversion based on the current culture of your machine and this could be agreeable or not depending on your intentions.

```
if(double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out x))
    .....
```

Using [Culture.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) means that the parsing is executed using the default operating system culture that it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.

**An important benefit of `TryParse`** is that you avoid the code to handle the possible exceptions raised by the simple Parse method. Exceptions should be always avoided as a method to control the flow of your program when you have alternatives. (Performance hit).

Comment: as it appears from his question,I think he's not concerned with any particular culture..He's using `InvariantCulture`..Though I assume that he's aware of what it means

Comment: Yes I don't want this to be dependent on the system language settings

Comment: And in this case you should use the CultureInfo approach. Here a [list of possible Culture Names](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
Double.Parse(num,nfi);
```